# Shall we increase the [acceleration] rate of this tag to the dump?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I've come across the [acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/acceleration) tag recently, and I think it should be burninated. Its own tag wiki excerpt condemns it:

> ambiguous tag: avoid

The tag wiki isn't any better:

> This tag is currently ambiguous and unlikely to get your question extra attention. Consider using the following tags for better classification:
>
> ...

As the tag wiki says, there are better tags for specific cases of acceleration, which add much more useful information to the post than the current [acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/acceleration) tag. All the questions tagged [acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/acceleration) use it in a different way.

I also think it does not meet the burnination criteria.

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

No. It does not describe its contents very well, and it is very ambiguous.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

It completely depends on how its used.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Definitely not. It is used for hardware acceleration, performance, game physics, and many other things, most of which have their own better, more specific tags.

Shall we burninate this tag?

Comment: What is said in the wiki doesn't really matter. Answer the [burnination criteria](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) in your question, backed with evidence. Based on what is currently in the question, the answer to "shall we burninate this tag?" is *no*, despite the upvotes.

Comment: The part of the tag wiki which didn't make it into your quote makes it look like it's useful as a signpost to better tags.

Comment: "1. [...] is it unambiguous?" No. "4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?" No. As @rene points out, these aren't sufficient to remove a tag whose ambiguous meanings are themselves valid topics for the site. But I imagine they may be sufficient to retag most posts using it. What's the analogous criteria post for [tag-disambiguation]?

Comment: @DamianYerrick there are none for that. We setup strict criteria for burnination as it causes much more friction while users seem eager to remove stuff. You're free to post an answer that says "no" and suggest the tag-disambigution with a plan.

Comment: Force burnination of mass * [acceleration] ?

Answer (score 25):

### Counterproposal: Accelerate toward disambiguation.

This tag currently looks like a candidate for disambiguation more than burnination. The current [burnination criteria](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070/2738262) require the concept to be off-topic for the site, and the meanings in [acceleration/info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/acceleration/info) are largely on-topic. So I'd recommend replacing `[burninate-request]` in the question with `[tags] [tag-disambiguation]`. Then for each of the currently 180 questions in [acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/acceleration), see which tag listed in the tag wiki best applies:

- For performance, use [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/performance), [hardware-acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hardware-acceleration), or [gpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gpu).
- For acceleration of a physical sensor, such as in a phone or a Wii Remote, use [accelerometer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/accelerometer).
- For physics simulation in games and otherwise, use [physics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/physics), [game-physics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game-physics), or [physics-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/physics-engine).

Comment: "require the concept to be off-topic for the site", the actual criteria, the one laid out by Shog, requires that it doesn't fail all questions. Here they decided that it should fail all questions instead.

Comment: I should note that burnination removes off-topic questions only. On-topic questions would be retagged in that process. Disambiguation means we keep the tag, which I don't think you're arguing for

Comment: @Machavity I seem to remember there being a bunch of "do not use" tags whose tag wiki acts as a signpost toward the preferred, less ambiguous tags.

Comment: Yes... but the number of people who don't read excerpts (let alone obey them) is enough to warrant fixing the tag. Watch the [seo] tag for a few days and see what I mean